# IsMouseOver Not Triggering for Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseover

The problem is `IsMouseOver` is not working when I hover the button, though I have customized the button and it is not working.

Can you say where is the error?

```xml
    <cc:CustomFlatButton Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="1,0,5,4"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Command疑い}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=疑いIsEnableFlag}">
             
            <Run FontWeight="Bold">
            疑い病名
        </Run>
             
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="cc:CustomFlatButton">

                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="メイリオ" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cc:CustomFlatButton}">
                            <Border Height="22"
                                    Margin="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="#FFFF5656"
                                    BorderThickness="2"
                                    CornerRadius="6"
                                    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                                    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                                    UseLayoutRounding="True">
                                <Label Padding="0,1,0,0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        Foreground="Black" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="cc:CustomFlatButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </cc:CustomFlatButton>
```

I have also checked if I use trigger `Property="IsMouseOver"`. It is also not working. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the Button Template and in this Template no property is bound to the Backgroud of the button.
In the trigger, you change the value of this property, but since no one uses this property, nothing changes in the display.

There are two main options to solve.

1. Set the Border's background binding to the Backgroud property of the button:

```xml
    <cc:CustomFlatButton Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="1,0,5,4"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Command疑い}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=疑いIsEnableFlag}">

        <Run FontWeight="Bold">
            疑い病名
        </Run>

        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="cc:CustomFlatButton">

                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="メイリオ" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">

                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cc:CustomFlatButton}">
                            <Border Height="22"
                                    Margin="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="#FFFF5656"
                                    BorderThickness="2"
                                    CornerRadius="6"
                                    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                                    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                                    UseLayoutRounding="True">
                                <Label Padding="0,1,0,0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        Foreground="Black" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="cc:CustomFlatButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </cc:CustomFlatButton>
```

2. Or change the Border background with ControlTemplate triggers.
   But this is applicable if CustomFlatButton is a Custom Control and not a UserControl.
   That is, the CustomFlatButton should not have any predefined XAML.

```xml
        <cc:CustomFlatButton Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="1,0,5,4"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Command疑い}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=疑いIsEnableFlag}">
             
            <Run FontWeight="Bold">
            疑い病名
        </Run>
             
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="cc:CustomFlatButton">

                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="メイリオ" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cc:CustomFlatButton}">
                            <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                                    Height="22"
                                    Margin="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="#FFFF5656"
                                    BorderThickness="2"
                                    CornerRadius="6"
                                    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                                    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                                    UseLayoutRounding="True">
                                <Label Padding="0,1,0,0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        Foreground="Black" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="cc:CustomFlatButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod" TargetName="PART_Border"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </cc:CustomFlatButton>
```